# Hiding classes - but unable to unit test

Tags: c#, oop, unit-testing

I am writing a project in C# using Visual Studio 2010 but wanted to use NUnit for unit testing.

I am quite new to oop but tried to go as far with information hiding and exposing only the minimum of interfaces required. This means that I have a couple classes which are entirely internal to the library - they can handle some internal state while the user only needs to be aware of a couple of public classes which provide an interface.

This seems to hide as much as possible, providing a minimal interface to the user.

However, if I want to unit test, I can't see a way to test these classes. So my question is what is best practice? Having to expose them purely for the sake of unit testing seems a shame.. or is there a better tool for the job?

It seems a trade off between encapsulating as much as possible and exposing as many methods as possible to allow them all to be tested - surely it would be best for unit testing to test the internal workings and let integration testing test the public interface?

--

I realise that normally, you would only worry about unit testing the public interface, but in this case that would lead to a lot of very convoluted tests - it is surely better to have everything broken down into small chunks to test?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I won't go into discussions whether it makes sense to test internal classes or not, but what you want can be achieved using [`InternalsVisibleTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute

Add following to your library:

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("MyTest")]
```

and all internal classes will be accessible from `MyTest.dll`

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a good start for testing. Still, if anyone has any feedback on the balance between encapsulation and testability, I would be very interested!

Comment: My 0.02$: I have a pragmatic approach to testing - if it is complex enough that it would benefit from testing, I test it regardless of whether it is public or internal. If I change it later, I update/remove tests - I have changed/removed public classes more then once, so I don't see that argument as valid. IMO, testing everything through public API is not unit test (as @Vorac correctly notes in his answer), but leaving that question aside, I prefer having test as close to the UUT as possible, to simplify the setup code and avoid false positives resulting from some other component being broken.

Comment: Thank you for confirming. This is what I thought.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Maybe I am misunderstanding either your situation, or what unit testing it. Read with a grain of doubt. Plus guide me with comments what the exact problem is.</sub>

Testing an API is in no way a unit test - it is called [system test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_testing)!

Unit tests take a *unit*, e.g. a class, at a time and model it's environment. Then assert that it behaves properly. For your private classes, the "environment" is the rest of the library.

Private data should not be made public for the sake of testing. Here is why. Private data is *implementation-specific*. That is, data formats should be able to freely change, without users of the classes API or unit tests noticing.

[This guy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_testing) explains it better than me.

Comment: This is exactly my thought - that black box testing (only the public parts) is closer to system testing than unit testing which should test the internal workings (white box). This was my issue until it was explained that you can test the internals using the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute. However, it still seems that many on this site and others believe you should not expose these private parts to the unit tests.